# Where does the root of this equation lie$?$

Tags: polynomials, roots, cubics

If $0\le p\le16$, then the equation $x^3-12x-p=0$ has one root in

> $(2,3)$

> $(3,4]$

> $(4,5)$

> None of these

My work:

I know that the function $f(x)=x^3-12x-p=0$ is strictly increasing in the intervals $(-\infty,-2)$ and $(2,\infty)$.

I also know that if $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are of opposite signs then at least $1$ or in general odd number of roots of the equation $f(x)=0$ lie between $a$ and $b$.

But I can't use these two pieces of information here.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Functional analysis! Please remove this tag.

Comment: As $f(x)$ is strictly increasing in all given intervals, then to have root in $(a,b)$ condition is $f(a)<0$, $f(b)>0$ and to have root in $(a,b]$ condition is $f(a)<0$, $f(b)\geq 0$.

Comment: $f(2)=-16-p<0$, $f(3)=-9-p < 0$, $f(4)=16-p\geq 0$, $f(5)=65-p > 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be helpful to start by "discarding" the constant term:  $ \ x^3 - 12x \ $ has zeroes $ \ 0 \  ,  \ \pm 2  \sqrt3 \ \approx \ \pm 3.5 \ \ $ and extrema at $ \ (-2 \ , \ 16) \ $ and $ \ (+2 \ , \ -16) \ \ . $  So shifting this function "downward" by $ \ 16 \ $ places the relative maximum on the $ x-$axis, making it a "double zero".  A little synthetic/polynomial division then gives us $ \ x^3 - 12x - 16 \ = \ (x + 2)^2·(x - 4) \ \ . $  So the "downward shift" keeps one zero within $ \ (3 \ , \ 4] \ \ . $

Answer (score 1):

Acrually I got the answer. Please check if I'm right.

$f(3)=-9-p$ which is always $\lt0$ and $f(4)=16-p$ which is either $\gt0$ or equal to $0$ or we can say that $f(3)\cdot f(4)\lt0$ or equal to $0$ $\implies$ there is one root in the interval $(3,4]$ (there is square bracket at the end because $f(4)$ can be $0$)

Comment: That is correct. You should also argue that the function can't have a root in any of the other intervals too.

Comment: Thanks sir.....We can deduce that other intervals can't be answer because of the same $f(a)\cdot f(b)$ theorem....btw do you know the proof of this

Comment: You don't need that fancy formal theorem. Just think about what "increasing" means when you are looking for roots in an interval and check the sign of the values at each end.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. You know the function is increasing from $x=2$ on so it has at most one root there. What are its values at $2$, $3$ and $4$?